# Viewbag is only grabbing information from final iteration of loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm trying loop through a list and put the contents into a viewbag. My problem is that when I grab the viewbag in the view, it's only showing me the contents from the final iteration of the loop. Any ideas on what is happening? Here is an example:

```
var output = new List<AirportsInACity>();

foreach (var airport in cities)
{
     var temp = new AirportsInACity();

     temp.airportName = airport.name
     temp.aircraftList = new List<AirportAircraftTypeList>();

     foreach (aircraft in airport.aircraftTypes)
     {
         aircraftTemp = new AirportAircraftTypeList();
         aircraftTemp.aircraftType = aircraft.AircraftType.AircraftTypeModel;
         aircraftTemp.seats = aircraft.Seats;
         aircraftTemp.attendants = aircraft.Attendants;

         temp.aircraftList.Add(aircraftTemp);

     }

     output.Add(temp);

     var outputStats = temp.AircraftList.GroupBy(p => p.aircraftType);

     foreach (var item in outputStats)
     {
         ViewBag.AirportName = temp.name;
         ViewBag.AirportAircraftType = item.Key;
         ViewBag.AircraftSeatsSum = item.Sum(p => p.seats);
     }
 }

 ViewBag.Output = output;
 return PartialView(output);
```

Now, lets say I have this information:

`Airport Name: JFK
 Aircraft Type: Boeing777
 Total Seats: 400`

`Airport Name: ATL
 Aircraft Type: Boeing777
 Total Seats: 800`

`Airport Name: LAS
 Aircraft Type: Boeing727
 TotalSeats: 150`

The problem is that in my Viewbag, it's only grabbing the last chunk of information (the LAS airport) but the console is outputting all of the information. What could the issue be?

Here is an example of what the view looks like:

```
@foreach (var item in Viewbag.Output)
{
    <td>@(ViewBag.AirportName)</td>
    <td>@(ViewBag.AirportAircraftType)</td>
    <td>@(ViewBag.AircraftSeatsSum)</td>
}
```

Comment: You must add items to a list and the list to the ViewBag

Comment: the items have been added to the list. Like I mentioned, in the console, all the right info is showing up, it's just not showing up in the View

Comment: @Max could you show me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create ExpandoObject and add it to the Details List.

Example:

Controller Code:

```
List<dynamic> Details = new List<dynamic>();

 foreach (var item in outputStats)
                {
                   dynamic detail;

                   detail = new ExpandoObject();
                   detail.AirportName  =temp.name;
                   detail.AirportAircraftType  = item.Key;
                   detail.AircraftSeatsSum =item.Sum(p => p.seats);

                  Details.Add(detail);
                }

ViewBag.Details = Details;
```

View Code:

```
@foreach (dynamic detail in ViewBag.Details)
{
   <td>@(detail.AirportName)</td>
        <td>@(detail.AirportAircraftType)</td>
        <td>@(detail.AircraftSeatsSum)</td>
}
```

Comment: I tried this, it's grabbing the right information, but it's only grabbing it from the last loop. it's not grabbing for each airport

Comment: added detail variable inside loop - should fix issue.

Answer (score 0):

On `ViewBag.Output` you have a list of type `AirportsInACity` with these properties: `airportName` and `aircraftList`  witch is a list of type `AirportAircraftTypeList`. Next you have a `foreach` into `outputStat' that setting always the **SAME** ViewBag item.

You must create a new viewmodel where put the `outputStats`

```
public class AircraftViewModel
{
    public string AirportName {get; set; }

    public string AirportAircraftType {get; set;}

    public int AircraftSeatsSum {get; set; }
}

[..]

var outputStats = temp.AircraftList.GroupBy(p => p.aircraftType);
List<AircraftViewModel> vm = new List<AircraftViewModel>();

     foreach (var item in outputStats)
     {
         var aircraft = new AircraftViewModel();
         aircraft.AirportName = temp.name;
         aircraft.AirportAircraftType = item.Key;
         aircraft.AircraftSeatsSum = item.Sum(p => p.seats);
         vm.Add(aircraft);
     }
 }

 ViewBag.Output = vm;
```